# Swift Json error garbage

Tags: php, json, swift

When I make a post request to my php api my swift application gives the error:

> Garbage at end

This is my json code (just for trying out):

```
    function getTips($params)
{
    $blessure = $params[0];
    switch($blessure)
    {
    case "hoofd":
        echo '
        "hoofd": [
                {
                    "naam": "neus in de kom",
                    "beschrijving": "neus zit in de kom",
                    "categorie": "hoofd"
                },
                {
                    "naam": "oor in de kom",
                    "beschrijving": "oor zit in de kom",
                    "categorie": "hoofd"
                }
            ]
        ';
     break;

     default:
     header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
     break;   
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send header

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

or put your data in assoc array and then wrap with json_encode, like this

```
echo json_encode( array(
   array( 'naam' => 'neus in de kom',
          'beschrijving'=> 'neus zit in de kom',
   ),
   array()
));
die();
```

just try)